# "Collapse" left-aligned breadcrumb and centered header into single line, but only if they don't overlap (no JavaScript)

Tags: html, css

**NOTE**: I want a CSS-only, no JavaScript solution, please. If that's not possible with CSS, then I need to avoid layout shift.

Consider this HTML content:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="breadcrumb">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="header">Bla bla bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

with this initial tentative CSS:

```css
.container {
  width: 360px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Imagine the `div.breadcrumb` is a breadcrumb and the `div.header` is, well, a header. The former is left-aligned and the latter is centered.

### What I need

Now I want to change the CSS (and the HTML if needed) so that, **if** the two texts are short enough that there is no horizontal overlap, the two divs "collapse" into one, or in other words, the lower div moves up as if the first didn't exist.

**But** if one of the texts is too long, so that the two texts horizontally overlap, then the collapse should **not** happen and everything would stay as initially shown.

The example above would become like this:

[image]

but if either of the texts were too long then it should look like this:

[image]

(i.e. just like the original)

### What I tried

So, my first attempt would be to add this to the CSS (in addition to the above):

```css
.breadcrumb {
  float: left;
}
```

But this has two issues:

1. As long as the two texts are short enough, it almost does the trick, but the header is centered within the space that remains to the right of the breadcrumbs, not centered to the total width.
2. When there is not enough space for both texts on one line, the header starts getting wrapped instead of going as a whole to a new line:

[image]

Even accepting issue 1, I tried to fix issue 2 with this:

```css
.breadcrumb {
  float: left;
}
.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I would expect this to fail when the header text itself is longer than what fits in one line (which would definitely be a problem, because I do have longer-than-one-line titles), but it fails even earlier:

[image]

I would expect it to go into a new line in this case, but either way, that wouldn't be a complete solution anyway.

### So, how do I do it?

Is it even possible in pure CSS?

Comment: Are you open to JavaScript because this is not possible with CSS and Html only

Comment: If you're positive it's not possible, that's an answer. I would be happy with a JavaScript solution as long as it takes care of avoiding the layout shift.

Comment: (The subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371310/why-didnt-i-get-a-notification-about-an-answer-to-my-question).)

Answer (score 1):

I altered some of the HTML and CSS to get the desired result.

As you will see, that `header` is not centered, so I added some extra container to center it in its spanning area. You can change that according to needs.

If you want to center the header exactly than you can play around the `position: absolute` property and change it to `position: relative` when `flex-flow: column` is activated.

`flex-flow` will be very useful in your case. So when it exceeds a certain word limit you can change the flow from `row`(default) to `column`.

```js
function contentWidth() {
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
  var containerText = document.getElementsByClassName("containerText");

  let lengths = Array.from(containerText).map(e => e.innerHTML.length);
  // Lengths take the length of the letters in the
  // container text using the mapping function

  let max = Math.max(...lengths);
  // Now we will calculate the maximum value from both of
  // the text. This is done so that if any of them
  // exceeds word limit than they get spanned in
  // new lines (sort of)

  if (max > 20) { // You can define any letter limit to make both span in new lines
    container[0].style.flexFlow = "column"
  }
}
contentWidth();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 360px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: block
}

.reed {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.breadcrumb {
  flex-shrink: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="breadcrumb containerText">Lorem ipsumsd</div>
  <div class="reed">
    <div class="header containerText">Bla bla bla bla bla</div>
  </div>
</div>
with this initial tentative CSS:

<div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help, but I have no difficulty in getting the desired result with JavaScript. I was asking for a CSS-only solution, I'll edit my question to make that clearer. Actually I could do with a JavaScript solution as long as it is run soon enough so as to not cause any layout shift (i.e. "jump"), so I'll investigate that.